# Reshaping the dataframe with duplicate elements in column R

Tags: r

My df looks like,

```
 id      event            time_diff
  1      a               0
  1      b               10
  3      a               0
  3      b               10
  3      c               5
  3      d               20
  3      d               30
```

I'm trying to reshape the above data in the following way,

```
 id    a   b   c   d
  1    0   10  NA  NA
  2    0   10  5   50
```

I tried,

```
  df2 <- dcast(df,id~event,fill="time_diff")
```

and also the following,

```
  df2 = df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  spread(Event,time_diff)
```

But both are not yielding the required results, any help would be appreciated.

PS: The main issue is it has duplicate events in different time frame, which I want to aggregate

Comment: Try `dcast(df,id~event,value.var="time_diff")`

Comment: @Jaap Unsure or out of votes? (for not hammering)

Comment: @BhargavRao out of votes ;-)

Comment: @Jaap *Sigh*, You need to wait for 10 hrs :-(

Comment: By adding an index column to the dataframe, and then using dcast function, will be useful such as:                                                                                    df$index=1:nrow(df)   df1=dcast(df,id+index~event,value.var="time_diff")